# I cannot link fortran code to my own C code on my laptop

Tags: c, makefile, linker, fortran

I know this issue has been discussed several times here, but I cannot find help from the previous threads.

Here's the deal. I use a code written in fortran and I link it to my code in C by my makefile. The fortran makefile is ready to handle the compatibility, in fact, I got the command

> CDEFS: -DAdd_

On my work machine everything seems fine. I do the link and run my own code.
However, I just tried to use the same code on my laptop and I got the classical linker error like:

`undefined reference to 'dtrsm_'` or 
`undefined reference to 'dcopy_'`

refering to the fortran program. Nevertheless, the compilers are the same gcc and f95 for both machines and I didn't touch anything from the makefile.
How come I got this error?

thanks for help me.

EDIT1: sure, this is my makefile and MUMPS is the fortran code that uses a own makefile.

```
ROOT = $(addprefix $(PWD), /)
BUILDS_DIR = $(addprefix $(ROOT), builds/)
SRCS_DIR   = $(addprefix $(ROOT), src/)
INCS_DIR   = $(addprefix $(ROOT), src/)
OBJS_DIR   = $(addprefix $(SRCS_DIR), objects/)
LIBS_DIR   = ./

MUMPS_DIR      = $(MUMPS_ROOT)
MUMPS_INCS_DIR = $(addprefix $(MUMPS_DIR), /include)
MUMPS_LIB_DIR  = $(addprefix $(MUMPS_DIR), /lib)
MUMPS_MPI_DIR  = $(addprefix $(MUMPS_DIR), /libseq)

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCS_DIR)*.c)
OBJS = $(SRCS:$(SRCS_DIR)%.c=$(OBJS_DIR)%.o)
MUMPS  = MUMPS

TARGET = APOGEE

EXES = $(addprefix $(BUILDS_DIR), $(TARGET))

CC       = gcc
CFLAGS   = -O3 -MD -DTRILIBRARY
INCLUDES = -I$(INCS_DIR) -I$(MUMPS_INCS_DIR)
# CL       = gcc
FL       = f95
LFLAGS   = -O
LIBS     = -L$(LIBS_DIR) -lm -lblas -lpthread
LIBS    += -L$(MUMPS_LIB_DIR) -ldmumps -lmumps_common -lpord -L$(MUMPS_MPI_DIR) -lmpiseq

RM = rm -f
.PHONY: all $(MUMPS) $(TARGET) distclean clean
default: $(MUMPS) $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Compiled $(TARGET) successfully! ***\n" ;
    $(FL) $(LFLAGS) -o $(BUILDS_DIR)$@ \
        $(OBJS) \
        $(LIBS)
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Linking $(TARGET) completed! ***\n"
$(OBJS): $(OBJS_DIR)%.o : $(SRCS_DIR)%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) \
        -c $<\
        -o $@
$(MUMPS): 
    (cd $(MUMPS_DIR) ; $(MAKE) ; cd $(ROOT)) ;
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Compiled $(MUMPS) successfully! ***\n" ;
distclean: clean
    $(RM) $(EXES)
    (cd $(MUMPS_DIR) ; $(MAKE) clean ; cd $(ROOT)) ;
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Purge $(MUMPS) and $(TARGET) completed! ***\n"
clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS_DIR)*.o \
        $(SRCS_DIR)*~
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Cleanup $(TARGET) completed! ***\n"
depend: $(SRCS)
    makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^
```

EDIT2: chunks of the MUMPS makefile is here
    include Makefile.inc

```
mumps_lib: requiredobj
    (cd src ; $(MAKE) $(ARITH))
requiredobj: Makefile.inc $(LIBSEQNEEDED) $(libdir)/libpord$(PLAT)$(LIBEXT)
# dummy MPI library (sequential version)
libseqneeded:
    (cd libseq; $(MAKE))
# Build the libpord.a library and copy it into $(topdir)/lib
$(libdir)/libpord$(PLAT)$(LIBEXT):
    if [ "$(LPORDDIR)" != "" ] ; then \
      cd $(LPORDDIR); \
      $(MAKE) CC="$(CC)" CFLAGS="$(OPTC)" AR="$(AR)" RANLIB="$(RANLIB)" OUTC=$(OUTC) LIBEXT=$(LIBEXT); \
    fi;
    if [ "$(LPORDDIR)" != "" ] ; then \
      cp $(LPORDDIR)/libpord$(LIBEXT) $@; \
    fi;
```

and in Makefile.inc we got:

```
PLAT    = 
LIBEXT  = .a
OUTC    = -o 
OUTF    = -o 
RM      = /bin/rm -f
CC      = cc
FC      = f95
FL      = f95
AR      = ar vr 
RANLIB  = ranlib
INCSEQ  = -I$(topdir)/libseq
LIBSEQ  = -L$(topdir)/libseq -lmpiseq

LIBBLAS = -lblas
LIBOTHERS = -lpthread

CDEFS = -DAdd_
OPTF    = -O
OPTC    = -O -I.
OPTL    = -O

INCS = $(INCSEQ)
LIBS = $(LIBSEQ)
LIBSEQNEEDED = libseqneeded
```

Comment: Where do the symbols come from? Show some code.

Comment: You probably need to link against LAPACK and BLAS...

Comment: What OS is on your laptop? Does it have the blas-devel and lapack-devel packages installed?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I guess I got both blas and lapack.

Comment: No guessing: does `apt-get install blas-devel lapack-devel` say that these are already installed, or does it install them for you? If the latter, does your link then succeed?